# How can I tell whether or not a film has been broadcast on TV?

Tags: film-industry

Is there any way to determine whether or not a film has been broadcast on a TV station (particularly in the UK)?

Answer (score 2):

**For the UK:**

The BUFVC has an [archive of UK TV listings](http://bufvc.ac.uk/tvandradio/trilt/) back to 2001. You need to be a member to access the full archive, but you can search the previous 2 weeks for free.

Alternatively, you can try [The Guardian's TV Guide](http://tvlistings.guardian.co.uk/default.aspx) it's a bit hit and miss and it only tells you what channel the film was last broadcast on. For example it will tell me that [The Shawshank Redemption](http://tvlistings.guardian.co.uk/search/?tvgSearchPhrase=The%20Shawshank%20Redemption) was on ITV2, [12 Angry Men](http://tvlistings.guardian.co.uk/search/?tvgSearchPhrase=%2212%20Angry%20Men%22) was on Sky movies crime & horror and that [Rollerball](http://tvlistings.guardian.co.uk/search/?tvgSearchPhrase=Rollerball) was on TCM2.